# Attempting to boot into Mac partition after Boot Camp results in a password lock

Tags: macos, firmware-password

I have just installed Windows on my Mac and it worked well, but after finishing and trying to go to Mac partition it is shown on the screen a lock icon with a password field. I tried to enter different password, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I believe you're looking at the firmware password:

[image]

This isn't specific for Boot Camp, and would have been set through the Firmware Password Utility. If you can't remember the password you set and can't boot into Mac, [you'll need to go to an Apple Store](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3554?).